# Getting AccessDenied when trying to retrieve a file from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to retrieve a file from an S3 bucket (using boto3), but I keep getting "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied". Below is how I created the S3 bucket:

```
    # S3
    bucket = s3.Bucket(
        self,
        "testS3Bucket",
        bucket_name=f"test_s3_bucket",
        versioned=True,
    )
    bucket.grant_read_write(service_lambda)
```

and the method I used to get the file from S3:

```
def download_file(self, file_name, s3_bucket):
    try:
        file = self.s3.Bucket(s3_bucket).Object(file_name)
        file_content = file.get()["Body"].read()
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "404":
            log.error("File does not exist for partner")
            return {}
        else:
            raise e
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    return file_content.decode()
```

I even went as far as to add "s3:*" action to the IAM policy statement, but I still got the same error. I was able to use the command below to successfully retrieve the file's metadata so I don't think it is a permissions error.

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket test_s3_bucket --key configuration.txt
```

Comment: If AWS error is saying it is a permission issue, it is a permission issue. you could try taking a look at CloudTrail to get more information on the principal denied but basically the role that is trying to access the file (if you are using lambda, then the role you specified for lambda to use) does not have permission to read the file content.

Comment: Is the code running in an AWS Lambda function? If so, you need to grant permissions in the IAM Role associated with the Lambda function. Simply assigning `bucket.grant_read_write(service_lambda)` will _not_ give permission to your Lambda functions to access the bucket.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same set of credentials in the working and non-working case. Use STS GetCallerIdentity (or the relevant awscli/SDK option) for each.